# transparent png not showing video in background

Tags: html, css, video, alpha

I made a transparent png with a theatre setup thing and i'm putting a 1 second video to play like a gif in the background but instead of seeing the video i see a body background color background, also letting z index be smaller than the other one, but deleting it on inspect element will show the video.

This is not the original one just that to show the problem

```html
<div id="bg" style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
 <img style='width:100%;height:100%;' alt='[]' src="http://www.moviebowlgrille.com/img/nav/rental.png">
 <video style='width:100%;height:100%;' alt='[]' autoplay loop>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Unfortunately, this site cannot run on your computer. Please upgrade your browser/buy a new computer.
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (so we can replicate the problem). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: uh ok ill do that

Comment: done, is that ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need of css declaration `background-color: transparent` to see the video above a transparent color. Moreover, you need of css declaration `position: absolute` to position both image and video on the top. So, the css rule could be the following: `img {position: absolute; background-color: transparent;}`
Note that the rules assigned to #bg may be useless.

I hope I was of any help.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg" style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
 <img style='width:100%;height:100%;' alt='[]' src="http://www.moviebowlgrille.com/img/nav/rental.png">
 <video style='width:100%;height:100%;' alt='[]' autoplay loop>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Unfortunately, this site cannot run on your computer. Please upgrade your browser/buy a new computer.
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works great! On phone it doesn't work though (may just be that html5 video is not supported)

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the video if you want to, if you have a video editing software you can place the PNG file ontop of your video, its less programming so its easier for your host to run your site.

Comment: no, the background image needs to be stretched, the video no.
could be a possibility but not in my case